# How can I use ElementTree to find all top level matched nodes?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an unknown XML structure where I would like to find all nodes with a `Name` attribute containing `FooBar` that don't themselves have a similar ancestor. That is to say, all highest level matching nodes excluding their children.

This is the current prototype code I have for finding nodes with the matching attribute. ElementTree doesn't have full XPath implementation so we cannot use `contains()`.

```
    found = []
    for node in root.iter():
        if 'FooBar' in node.attrib.get('Name', ''):
            found.append(node)
```

There appears to be ways of getting the parent through `.find('..')`, but this also returns `null` when you call it from the node you start with.

Example Input:

```
<root>
    <ElementTypeA Name="..........FooBar.">
        ...
        <ElementTypeB Name=".......FooBar......."/>
        <ElementTypeC Name="...FooBar..........."/>
        <ElementTypeD Name="....................."/>
        <ElementTypeE Name="..........FooBar.">
        .....
        </ElementTypeE>
        ...
    </ElementTypeA>

    <ElementTypeF Name="...........">
        <ElementTypeG Name="..........FooBar.">
            ...
            <ElementTypeH Name=".......FooBar......."/>
            <ElementTypeI Name="..........FooBar.">
            .....
            </ElementTypeI>
            ...
        </ElementTypeG>
    </ElementTypeF>
</root>
```

In the above input, only ElementTypeA and ElementTypeG should be selected. ElementTypeE has a matching ancestor while ElementTypeF is not matching.

Comment: Can you provide sample input & output?
If i understood correctly, then you want to find all the nodes with attribute name 'Name'  & its values 'FooBar'. And these nodes can't have similar ancestor(parent nodes with same names).

Comment: @VinodSharma Yes, but the `Name` can partially match. I've added an example for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cries out for recursion.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def recur(node):
    # if this node is a foobar, return a one-item list containing it
    if 'Name' in node.attrib:
        if "FooBar" in node.attrib['Name']:
            return [ node ]
    # otherwise return a list of the results on the children
    found = []
    for child in node:
        found += recur(child)
    return found

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(recur(root))
```

Output:

```
[<Element 'ElementTypeA' at 0x7f3890ef4dd0>, <Element 'ElementTypeG' at 0x7f3890eea310>]
```